# Finding a matrix with given eigenvalues that most closely approximates another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Let $A \in {\bf C}^{n \times n}$ be a given matrix and let $\lambda_1 , \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n$ be a given collection of $n$ complex numbers (not necessarily distinct), and let $\|\centerdot\| $ be some given matrix norm.  How do you find $B \in {\bf C}^{n \times n}$ such that $\lambda_1 , \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $B$ and $\|A-B\|$ is minimal?

I don't think that there is a general analytic procedure for finding such a matrix, but I was wondering if there are numerical methods for approximating $B$. I think it could be done by considering the Schur decomposition of $B = QUQ^{-1}$ where the diagonal of $U$ is the set of given eigenvalues, but I'm unsure of how to simultaneously minimize over all possible unitary matrices $Q$ and all possible entries above the main diagonal of $U$.

Comment: Assume $A$ is non-singular/normal.  Since change of basis matrix is unitary, it preserves the norm so assume that $A = (\alpha_i)$ is diagonal.  The best approximation $B$ is just the diagonal matrix $(\lambda_j)$ arranged so that $|\alpha_i - \lambda_i|$ is minimized.  So to compute it, you'd compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$ and compute your change of basis matrices onto the eigenvectors of $A$, then change the basis back.  For the general non-singular case, use the QZ decomp and the same argument.  For singular matrices there seems to be some case-checking, but doable.

Comment: @JohnSamples what if the norm is not unitary invariant?

Comment: I mean, what norm are you using?  You are asking the question for an arbitrary norm?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested for the case of an arbitrary norm, which is sort of why I was skeptical about finding a general analytic answer, but your comment is very helpful for the common unitary invariant norms.  I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I think there is some theorem for finite-dimensional spaces that every matrix norm can be decomposed as some linear function on the usual one plus some 'atomic' norms, but I don't know the precise statement.  You would probably figure out how to change a given norm to the usual one, then compute there.  Or possibly there is an algorithm for determining the 'unitary' group relative to an arbitrary norm.